# List template not displaying in subsites sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I have saved a list template in list template gallery from a subsite. It is visible in list template gallery and I am able to create list in root site. But when I go to another subsite I am not able to see that list template. Why it is happening?

Comment: It can happen if the list template depends on a particular feature such as `Publishing` which might be activated at root site but not at the child site.